# Creating a table from an API response using PySpark

Tags: python, string, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Response to one of my API calls is as below:

```
{
    "requestId": "W2840866301623983629",
    "items": [
        {
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "code": 0,
            "apId": "amor:h973hw839sjw8933",
            "data": {
                "parentVis": 4836,
                "parentmeet": 12,
                "vis": 908921,
                "out": 209481
            }
        },
        {
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "code": 0,
            "apId": "complex:3d180779a7ea2b05f9a3c5c8",
            "data": {
                "parentVis": 5073,
                "parentmeet": 9,
                "vis": 623021,
                "out": 168209
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a table as below:

```
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|status     |code   |apId                   |parentVis      |parentmeet |vis        |out        |
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|SUCCESS    |0      |amor:h973hw839sjw8933  |4836           |12         |908921     |209481     |
|SUCCESS    |0      |amor:p0982hny23        |5073           |9          |623021     |168209     |
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I tried to store the API response as string and tried `sc.parallelize`, but I was unable to achieve the result.
Can someone please help me with the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(data['items']) 

df.show()
```

that should do it (assuming your json sits in `data` dict)

Answer (score 1):

If your response is a string...

```py
s = """{"requestId":"W2840866301623983629","items":[{"status":"SUCCESS","code":0,"apId":"amor:h973hw839sjw8933","data":{"parentVis":4836,"parentmeet":12,"vis":908921,"out":209481}},{"status":"SUCCESS","code":0,"apId":"complex:3d180779a7ea2b05f9a3c5c8","data":{"parentVis":5073,"parentmeet":9,"vis":623021,"out":168209}}]}"""
```

you can use `json` library to extract the outer layer and then describe what's inside to extract that too.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import json

data_cols = ['parentVis', 'parentmeet', 'vis', 'out']
df = spark.createDataFrame(json.loads(s)['items']).select(
    'status', 'code', 'apId',
    *[F.col("data")[c].alias(c) for c in data_cols]
)

df.show(truncate=0)
# +-------+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+------+------+
# |status |code|apId                            |parentVis|parentmeet|vis   |out   |
# +-------+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+------+------+
# |SUCCESS|0   |amor:h973hw839sjw8933           |4836     |12        |908921|209481|
# |SUCCESS|0   |complex:3d180779a7ea2b05f9a3c5c8|5073     |9         |623021|168209|
# +-------+----+--------------------------------+---------+----------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API response is a dictionary, this should suffice

Store the API response in a dictionary:

```
    dictionary = {
        "requestId": "W2840866301623983629",
        "items": [
            {
                "status": "SUCCESS",
                "code": 0,
                "apId": "amor:h973hw839sjw8933",
                "data": {
                    "parentVis": 4836,
                    "parentmeet": 12,
                    "vis": 908921,
                    "out": 209481
                }
            },
            {
                "status": "SUCCESS",
                "code": 0,
                "apId": "complex:3d180779a7ea2b05f9a3c5c8",
                "data": {
                    "parentVis": 5073,
                    "parentmeet": 9,
                    "vis": 623021,
                    "out": 168209
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

1. Create the schema based on the input API response providing the datatypes and all
   from pyspark.sql.types import *

   ```
    schema = StructType([ \
        StructField("status",StringType(),True), \
        StructField("code",StringType(),True), \
        StructField("apId",StringType(),True), \
        StructField("data",
                        StructType([\
                        StructField("parentVis", IntegerType(),True), \
                        StructField("parentmeet", IntegerType(),True), \
                        StructField("vis", IntegerType(),True),\
                        StructField("out", IntegerType(),True)\
                        ]) ,True), \
    ])
   ```
2. Create a dataframe using dictionary and using the above created schema

   ```
    df = spark.createDataFrame(dictionary['items'],schema = schema)
   ```
3. Then create a new dataframe out of by selecting the nested columns as follows:
   from pyspark.sql.functions import *

   ```
    df1 = df.select(col('status'),col('code'),col('apId'),col('data.parentVis'),col('data.parentmeet'),col('data.vis'),col('data.out'))
    df1.show(truncate = False)
   ```

Please check the below image for reference:
[image]